# How to read elm327 wifi obd2 from raspberry terminal or python code from raspberry?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, obd-ii, elm327

I have bought a OBD2 Wifi connector from amazon ([https://www.amazon.com/dp/B06XRVYDMG/ref=cm_sw_r_sms_tai_2lkxAb...#immersive-view_1516052760812](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XRVYDMG)), I'm able to read the data from their app. But when I'm trying to read from Raspberry Terminal through netcat as specified in the blog (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61424/wi-fi-enabled-odbii-script) by passing the Mode (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs) its not showing any result.

Please advice how to read the OBD2 data.

Thanks,
PSA

Comment: This is a very broad question, unfortunately lacking a lot of details to be answered. What exactly happens, when you communicate through `netcat`? Can you show us a communication log? ELM327-compatible adapters need to be initialized using `AT` commands before you can communicate via `PIDS`, did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to make this work. Had to make a virtual serial port ttyUSB0 with socat on raspbian stretch.

socat pty,link=/dev/ttyUSB0,waitslave tcp:192.168.0.10:35000&

Then I followed these instructions

http://www.cowfishstudios.com/blog/obd-pi-raspberry-pi-displaying-car-diagnostics-obd-ii-data-on-an-aftermarket-head-unit

python obd_gui.py

[obd_gui screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2c3Z.jpg)